# Prompt for input and print a response with only one printf()?

Tags: c, string, printf

C-code only: Ask user if they are married or not. User must input 0 for false. User must input any other character for true. Do it using only one printf.

Ok, so I always turn to stackoverflow as a last resort, because I am trying to figure it out. This, is what I came up with but I get errors and I have done other things like take out `scanf("%f", &t)`, because that is essentially unnecessary. I also made `char married[3];` `char married[] ="`; instead but that doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char married[3];

    unsigned long t;
    int f;
    scanf("%f", &t);
    scanf("%d", &f);

    printf(" For the following question: Enter 0 if false. Enter anything but 0 if true. Are you married? %s", married);

    if (f == 0)
    {
        married == "no";
    }
    else
        married == "yes";
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks the help is appreciated. Please go easy on me just learning...

Comment: `married == "no";` test their equality, which will never be true, then throw the result away. It's obviously not what you want.

Comment: What is the required output of the program? In any case, any solution is likely to have the `scanf` after the `printf`. Because of course the prompt to the user must come before the reading of the user input.

Comment: Why does your program wait for the user to enter a number *before* it asks the user to enter a number?

Comment: Why do you display `married` before you (try to) give it a value?

Comment: Every thing seems in the wrong order. You print `married`, before trying to set it

Comment: It is due to the constraint of having to use printf once. @immibis

Comment: In addition to all the comments above, `scanf("%f", &t)` is extremely wrong for `unsigned long t`, which BTW, is not used **anywhere** in your code (which BTW, is really bad quality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you are interpreting the question correctly. It says to print whether the person is married or not. So that's the expected output. It suggests you can do that with one printf. It does not mean the whole program only has one printf so you are allowed to have another printf for the user prompt. It just means avoid using two printfs for the output (one for YES and another for NO). One way to do this is to use the ? operator.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int married = 1;

    printf(" For the following question: Enter 0 if false. Enter anything but 0 if true. Are you married?");
    scanf("%d", &married);

    printf("You %s married\n", married ? "ARE" : "ARE NOT");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char married[4]; //Space for 'yes' + the NUL-terminator
    //unsigned long t; Why do you have this?
    int f = 1; //Initialize variables

    //scanf("%f", &t); ??
    //scanf("%d", &f); Wrong place

    printf(" For the following question: Enter 0 if false. Enter anything but 0 if true. Are you married?"); //Remove %s and the argument. You are trying to print an uninitialized array
    scanf("%d", &f); //scan input after printing

    if (f == 0) 
        strcpy(married, "no");
    else
        strcpy(married, "yes"); //Copy strings using strcpy function

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yet, the program outputs nothing (not your fault, that's how OP is currently doing it, see the second comment to the question).

Comment: Thanks bud! Yeah, like I said I deleted that, but I was undoing all my coding to get back to a place where it was working; that's why I explained above about the unsigned long t.Otherwise, great work. Thanks for teaching me string copy :). But, I get this error `Warning 2 warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead.` I'm guessing this code is making the presumption that the user is married by default, bc `int f = 1;`, but I don't know if scanning for the input would be found if it was not initialized to an integer.

Comment: @mwf1234: In this case it means - You. See [What does OP mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146513/267240).

Comment: If the second comment you are referring to is @alanau then that doesn't solve the answer. That is shown in the code above by coolguy

Comment: @mwf1234: 1. The statement "solve the answer" is meaningless. 2. Both your question and the answer above (which relies on the code in your question) do not address this issue - the code outputs NOTHING!!!

Comment: @barakmanos Create a C-program that uses the fact that 0 (zero) is interpreted as FALSE and non-zero is interpreted as TRUE. The C-program can be made easier to read when this 0 (or non-zero) is assigned to a variable e.g. an int called married. Use the ?: operator to print if someone is married or not. (See if you can use a single printf)

Comment: @mwf1234: 1. You have not answered my comment above (this perhaps refers to my comment on your question). 2. You are not using the ternary (`?:`) operator anywhere in your code. 3. The requirement to use `printf` only once seems rather odd. Are you sure that this is really part of the requirements? You could always use `puts` instead, but honestly - I see no challenge here.

Comment: @barakmanos I thought ?: was a typo. I'm not familiar with c I am just learning it. After learning about puts, I will try to implement them.

Comment: @mwf1234 I'm not sure you are interpreting the question correctly. It says to print whether the person is married or not. So that's the expected output. It suggests you can do that with one `printf`. It does not mean the whole program only has one `printf` so you are allowed to have another `printf` for the user prompt. It just means avoid using two `printfs` for the output (one for YES and another for NO). One way to do this is to use the `?` operator.

Comment: Thanks @AlanAu it is greatly appreciated. I am excited to learn and get this done correctly. Thanks for the clarification; it is a life saver.